# How to filter content between specific keywords using grep?

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I got a bunch of files, and I want to find out the content between two tags `st` and `et`.
if I use `grep "st.*et" files`, I will get these two tags involved in the result.
Such as `st Hello world! et`.
But I just need the `Hello world!` part.

Is there a way to show only the content between the tags using grep(or other regex tools)?

---

PS: I know how to use tools such as `AWK`, `python` to do further-processing with these results to reach my goal. But I just wonder there could be a more direct way to do that.

Comment: Does your version of grep support PCRE mode?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add i) your operating system, UNIX grep and GNU/Linux grep are very different; ii) an example of your input file and your desired output. What's a "tag"? Do you mean `<st>`? Or just the string `st`? Would `foostbar` count? Will the two "tags" always be on the same line or do you need to match across multiple lines?

Answer (score 5):

Using GNU `grep` built with recent PCRE support:

```
echo 'st Hello world! et' | grep -oP "st\K.*?(?=et)"
```

The key here is to use the look-ahead and look-behind zero-length assertions.

```
\K     ==>  Look-behind assertion
(?=et) ==>  Look-ahead assertion
```

For more info, you could read [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Comment: Possibly right before the limit of the irrelevance, but If I can suggest something `grep -oP 'st\K.*(?=et)'` would be of greater effect to show that it works. Also I don't understand the `\s` in place of the ` `, it's a space, so why don't just match a space?

Comment: @kos Yep. You're right. Now, made it more relevant. I just quickly answered the question without giving much thought.

Answer (score 4):

You may want to use `sed`:

```
sed -n 's/.*st\(.*\)et.*/\1/p'
```

Comment: This command searched the `st content et` pattern, and replaced it with ` content `, then printed it out. Nice trick. So, pure regex can't do what I'm looking for?

Comment: @Zen; Yes, "pure" (standard) regexp won't do that because you have a matching context that's not part of the desired result; so you need some means to strip your data from that surrounding context. - There's some extensions available in some tools that support it; have a look at the other answer for one (non-standard) way to address such a task.

Comment: @Zen a regex engine that supports lookarounds can do it perfectly well, we just can't be sure what tools you have available that support that unless you tell us your OS.